# Efficient calculation of frequencies of multiindexed category variables

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I'm considering a multiindexed `(i,j,k)` DataFrame with one column that contains three categorical variables `A`, `B` or `C`.

I want to compute the frequency of the variables for each `i` over all `(j,k)`. I have a solution, but I think there exists a more pythonic and efficient way of doing it.

The code for a MWE reads (in reality `len(I)*len(J)*len(K)` is large, in the millions, say):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

I = range(10)
J = range(3)
K = range(2)

data = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 3, size=len(I)*len(J)*len(K)),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([I, J, K]),
    columns=['cat']
)

data.index.names = ['i', 'j', 'k']

data[data['cat'] == 0] = 'A'
data[data['cat'] == 1] = 'B'
data[data['cat'] == 2] = 'C'


data = data.unstack(['j', 'k'])
result = data.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0) / (len(J)*len(K))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby`, and also normalize your `value_counts`:

```py
data.groupby(level=0)['cat'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(level=1).fillna(0)
```

To compare, first let's make the dummy data big (60 million rows):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

I = range(100000)
J = range(30)
K = range(20)

data = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 3, size=len(I)*len(J)*len(K)),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([I, J, K]),
    columns=['cat']
)

data.index.names = ['i', 'j', 'k']

data[data['cat'] == 0] = 'A'
data[data['cat'] == 1] = 'B'
data[data['cat'] == 2] = 'C'
```

Timing your original method:

```py
data_interim = data.unstack(['j', 'k'])
data_interim.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0) / (len(J)*len(K))
```

gives (on my machine) 1min 24s ± 1.98 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

the alternative:

```py
data.groupby(level=0)['cat'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(level=1).fillna(0)
```

gives (on my machine) 8.86 s ± 216 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: It's got to be `data['cat'].groupby...` otherwise it does raise an attribute error, no?

Comment: Absolutely right - total copy paste fail! I've corrected the code now.

Comment: I made some suggestions of how to speed up your method even further; Grouping with `as_index=False` and pivoting instead of unstacking~ @s_pike

Answer (score 1):

Baseline for s_pike's method:

```
%%timeit 
(data.groupby(level=0)['cat']
     .value_counts(normalize=True)
     .unstack(level=1)
     .fillna(0))

6.41 s ± 243 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

If they're truly categorical, you can get a lot of benefit out of explicitly making the column categorical, and then using either of these methods.

They're both still about twice as fast without being categorical, but become about 3x as fast when made categorical.

```
data['cat'] = data['cat'].astype('category')
```

```
%%timeit
(data.groupby(level=0, as_index=False)['cat']
     .value_counts(normalize=True)
     .pivot(index='i', columns='cat', values='proportion'))

1.82 s ± 91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
(x := data.pivot_table(index='i', columns='cat', aggfunc='value_counts')).div(x.sum(1), 0)

1.8 s ± 107 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Outputs:

```
cat           A         B         C
i                                  
0      0.341667  0.318333  0.340000
1      0.311667  0.388333  0.300000
2      0.351667  0.350000  0.298333
3      0.363333  0.333333  0.303333
4      0.326667  0.350000  0.323333
...         ...       ...       ...
99995  0.315000  0.313333  0.371667
99996  0.323333  0.351667  0.325000
99997  0.305000  0.353333  0.341667
99998  0.318333  0.341667  0.340000
99999  0.331667  0.340000  0.328333

[100000 rows x 3 columns]
```